# i build drawer when when i tap on button it show me different error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, iso

when i click on the link in drawer it show me different error.

[image]

when i click on any drawer link it stuck and give me error message and took me to other error page.
*_************///////////////////////////////////////////////////////*************
[image]

*_************///////////////////////////////////////////////////////*************
[image]

*_************///////////////////////////////////////////////////////*************

[image]

*_************///////////////////////////////////////////////////////*************

```
class MainDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainDrawer({super.key});
  Widget buildListTitle(String title, IconData icon, Function function) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(
        icon,
        size: 20,
      ),
      title: Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'RobotoCondensed',
            fontSize: 24,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      onTap: function(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 120,
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            child: Text(
              'cooking up',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                fontSize: 30,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          buildListTitle("Meal", Icons.restaurant, () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/");
          }),
          buildListTitle("Meal", Icons.restaurant, () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(FilterScreen.routeName);
          }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume the error is coming from `FilterScreen`

Comment: i thing the guy below spoted the error. but when I put bracket with Function function() then the buildListtitle show me error.

Comment: i change the onTap: function() to onTap: function but now function giving error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `buildListTitle` change the `onTap: function()` to `onTap: function`

Comment: ok I'll trying it

Comment: Error: The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'.
main_drawer.dart:21
 - 'Function' is from 'dart:core'.
      onTap: function,

Comment: change the paremeters from `(String title, IconData icon, Function function)` to `(String title, IconData icon, void Function() function)`

Comment: ok i will try it let see

Comment: thank you so much bro its work . thank again. do you have linkdln

Comment: you're welcome bro. my linkedin: /mateushvenancio